# Set the value of element by classname, without having the element's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume that we have the following code:

```
<span class="input-text">
    <input type="search">
</span>
```

Is there any way, we could set the `value` of that without having the **ID** of the *element*?

Comment: The question is little unclear to me . your saying set value of element by class name and you did not give a class to your input tag instead to span tag please be little more specific , what does that mean in your question ? input or span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions are many. `.val('your value')` is the method to set the input tag value

**jQuery**

```
With class referring to span element
$('.input-text').find('input').val('value');
$('.input-text input').val('value'); // descendent selector
$('.input-text > input').val('value'); // direct children selector
Without referring to span element
$('input[type=search]').val('value'); // attribute selector
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.input-text').find('input')[0].value = 'value'
```

Or If you want to over write the content inside the `<span>` tag use

```
$('.input-text').html('content')
$('span.input-text').html('content')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :-

```
$(".input-text").children().val('set any value you want to')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('input[type="search"]').val("set your value");
```

Comment: Your are missing quotes and closing `]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('input[type="search"]').val("Your Value");
```

or

```
$('.input-text input').val("you value");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ludt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should refer **[jQuery selectors.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** This would be more helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

try [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) or `value`

```
$('input[type="search"]').val("Your Value");
```

or

```
$('input[type="search"]').value = "Your Value"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(".className").val("your value");
```

Comment: "Set the value of element by **classname**, without having the element's ID" that's the jquery classname selector

Comment: @niko "Set the **value** of element by **classname**, without having the element's ID" .html() isn't the value it's the **CONTENT**

Comment: I'll edit my post so maybe you guys can understand what I was trying to say. I hope it helped... duces!