# How to set select value dropdownlist in javascript via getElementByClassName or querySelector without id

Tags: javascript, html, dom, htmlcollection

I am trying set select value dropdownlist in javascript. I have dropdownlist like following:

```
<div class="gender_option" id="create">
    <span class="value">
        <select name="account" class="select-gender">
            <option value="Unknown">Please select</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Firstly i tried by getElementByClassName. I searched lots of answer-question in stackoverflow and applied but it doesn't work again. 
The below code is one of them. The code throws error like `undefined options`. I changed option instead of options but still doesn't work.

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('select_gender');
e[1].options[e[1].selectedIndex].selected=true;
```

I examined and applied lots of solution like following explainations: 
[Set the value of element by classname, without having the element's ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281939/set-the-value-of-element-by-classname-without-having-the-elements-id)
[How can I determine the value of the selected dropdown option using getElementsByClassName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445916/how-can-i-determine-the-value-of-the-selected-dropdown-option-using-getelementsb)

Also i found queryselector i tried following code that doesn't work.

```
var selectElement = document.querySelector('.select_gender');
var output1 = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;

for (var j=0; j<output1.length; j++) {
    if (radioElements[i].getAttribute('value') == 'MALE') {
         output1[j].selected=true;
    }
}
```

How can i set select value in javascript without id parameter

Ragards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var selectElement = document.querySelector('.select_gender');` contains a typo: `.select_gender` should be `.select-gender`. That's why `e[1].options[e[1].selectedIndex].selected=true;` gives you an error.

Anyway, you can use this [css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) to set the selected option of the selector to a certain option (e.g. Male)

```js
document.querySelector(".select-gender option[value='Male']").selected = true;

// now selectedIndex (of the *selector*) is 1
console.log(document.querySelector(".select-gender").selectedIndex);

// and its value = "Male"
console.log(document.querySelector(".select-gender").value);

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", setSelectorToFemale);

// set by finding the desired option
// not very practical, just to demo
function setSelectorToFemale() {
  const desiredValue = "Female";
  const foundOption = [...document.querySelectorAll(".select-gender option")]
  //             ^ spread ElementList to Array
    .find(o => o.value === desiredValue);
  //             ^ only option with value desiredValue
  if (foundOption) {
    foundOption.selected = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gender_option" id="create">
    <span class="value">
        <select name="account" class="select-gender">
            <option value="Unknown">Please select</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <button>Select Female</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Kooilnc. One of your solution is document.querySelector(".select-gender option[value='Male']").selected = true;
throwns error like "Cannot set property 'selected' of null".

Queryselector and cssselector are good approaches. But i couldn't understand return type. Is that same with html collection or different

Comment: Also other solution doesn't throw any error, but doesn't work. I changed like this:


`const desiredValue = "Female";
  const foundOption = [document.querySelectorAll(".select-gender option")]
  //             ^ spread ElementList to Array
    .find(o => o.value === desiredValue);
  //             ^ only option with value desiredValue
  if (foundOption) {
    foundOption.selected = true;
  } `

Comment: Dude, i examined your first line in the code with fresh head and success! i fixed! Thanks a tons of!

Answer (score 0):

this will now work but one has to ask why would you do this?  If you select a value it will become true all by itself

```js
function myFunction(){
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("select-gender");
e[0].options[e[0].selectedIndex].selected=true;

console.log(e[0].options);

console.log(e[0]);
}
```

```html
<div class="gender_option" id="create">
    <span class="value">
        <select name="account" class="select-gender" onchange='myFunction()'>
            <option value="Unknown">Please select</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay DCR. I have a project to automatically fill field in javascript. So i preferred this way instead of entering manually. Your code throws same error like "undefined options".

Comment: well, if the code works as a snippet but not on your website you must have something else going on.  can you share a link to your website?

Comment: are you using select-gender or still using the mistaken select_gender?

Comment: I am using select-gender i wrote mistakenly. I couldn't share my site works local network. Also i used tampermonkey in good faith but still doesn't work.

Comment: If you indicated following, like this

TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at Window.eval (userscript.html?id=93f905de-d448-41fe-abba-4ce7ed047b97:10364)
    at <anonymous>:3:75

Comment: there are a number of posts that mention problems with tampermonkey

Comment: I nearly examined all of them. Also I examined queryselector and getelementsbyid. But doesn't work.